# How I can check whether a column contains a substring of a given searchterm?

Tags: sqlite3

In sqlite I have the following table

```
 CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS redirect (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            url_from TEXT not null,
            url_to TEXT not null,
            method TEXT not null,
            http_status_code INTEGER not null CHECK( http_status_code IN (300,301,302,304,304,308,307) ) DEFAULT 301,
            use_in_https  INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_https IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 0,
            use_in_http  INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_http IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1,
            exact_match INTEGER not null CHECK(exact_match IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1
        );
```

And I insert the following values:

```
INSERT INTO redirect (url_from,url_to,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,use_in_https) VALUES
            ('http://google.com/mytest','http://yahoo.com','GET',301,1,1),
            ('http://google.com/mytest?param=hello','http://ikariam.gr','GET',301,1,1),
            ('http://google.com/mytest','http://yandex.com','GET',302,1,0)
```

In my app I search based on an incomming url and I want to find the best match:

If the url is `http://google.com/mytest` I want the following result to be returned:

| url_from | url_to | method | http_status_code | use_in_http | use_in_http |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [http://google.com/mytest'](http://google.com/mytest%27) | 'http://yahoo.com' | 'GET' | 301 | 1 | 1 |

But once I either for:

- `http://google.com/mytest/lorem_uipsus`
- `http://google.com/mytest?param=petralka`
- `http://google.com/mytest?param33=petralka`

I want this result to be returned:

| url_from | url_to | method | http_status_code | use_in_http | use_in_https |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [http://google.com/mytest'](http://google.com/mytest%27) | 'http://yandex.com' | 'GET' | 302 | 1 | 0 |

As you can see `request_from` may contain a subscript for the provided search term.

Therefore, I thought the query should be:

```
select 
  url_from,url_to,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,use_in_https
from
  redirect
where
  -- Here search by substring
  -- url_from must be a substring of a provided search term
order by exact_match DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But here I am stuck, how I can check that a column contains a substring of a provided  searchterm?

What I want is to do the opposite of:

```
url_from like '%input%
```

Meaning:

```
'input' like url_from
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `'input' like '%' || url_from || '%'` which concatenates the wildcard characters to the column so a contains-search can be ran against it? For example:

```
select url_from,url_to,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,use_in_https
from
  redirect
where
  'input' like '%' || url_from || '%'
order by exact_match DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `instr` gives me better results

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Not sure I understand. My answer gives you all of the applicable results.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to filter is:

1. if `exact_match` is true (1) then match the incomming searchterm exactly
2. if `exact_match` is false (0) then check if `url_from` is an subscript of the searchterm.

For the latter use the [`instr`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-instr/) function like this ():

```
select 
  url_from,url_to,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,use_in_https
from
  redirect
where
    ('http://google.com/mytest/lalala' = url_from and exact_match = 1)
   or 
    (instr('http://google.com/mytest/lalala',url_from) <> 0 and exact_match = 0)
order by exact_match DESC
LIMIT 1
```

For the case above I assume you want to search for the `http://google.com/mytest/lalala` string.

---

## Improvement

In case you want the best match (assuming that url_from will be all latin characters) then you'll have to do the following:

```
select 
  url_from,url_to,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,use_in_https
from
  redirect
where
    ('http://google.com/mytest/lalala' = url_from and exact_match = 1)
   or 
    (instr('http://google.com/mytest/lalala',url_from) <> 0 and exact_match = 0)
order by exact_match DESC, LENGTH(REPLACE(url_from,'http://google.com/mytest/lalala','')) desc
LIMIT 1
```

The idea behind is that the most matching substring will have the smallest non-matching substring. So If I remove the value from `url_from` column to my string that I search for (`google.com/mytest/lalala`) the less long remaining value will have the best match.

The rationale above works only under the following conditions:

### Condition 1

Both url_from and searchterm have a common part starting from the first letter.

What I mean is that if you search for `http://google.com/mytest/lalala`
all values at column `url_from` must start at least with these values:

1. `http://google.com`
2. `http://google.com/mytest`
3. `http://google.com/mytest/la`
4. `http://google.com/mytest/lala`

Because I assume that all matches will start from the first letter.

### Condition 2

The table must have the following unique index:

```
 UNIQUE(url_from,method,http_status_code,use_in_http,exact_match),
 UNIQUE(url_from,method,http_status_code,use_in_https,exact_match)
```

Given the application you want to make (Ι mean you may need different values and match for `use_in_http` and `use_in_https`)